# What does manipulating behaviour at runtime mean?

Tags: ios, objective-c, dynamic-programming

I have learned that using objective C's message dispatch system you can manipulate behaviour at runtime, such as method swizzling or even create classes at runtime.But what does it mean actually to change behaviour at runtime?

Comment: It means just what it says. You can reach right into a method implementation when the program is already running and change what it does. The code is self modifying. If you find that notion surprising, start by learning Ruby.

Comment: @TibinThomas Do you have any experience in C? If you do, I have a pretty elegant way of explaining this.

Comment: @Alexander Yes.It would be helpful for everyone to understand it better if you could explain it in C.

Comment: @TibinThomas Have you ever found yourself writing code like `Person *make_makePerson()`, `void delete_person()`, `int person_get_age(Person *p)`, etc? That's like a form of hand-rolled object oriented programming. You could imagine after a while, that you would want to have inheritance, but that doesn't fit your model. Suppose you have a `Student` type as a "subclass" of "Person". You wouldn't want to make a seperate function for every (type, method) combo. Instead what you could do, is make a generic "invoke method" funciton, which takes an object, a method name, and some args, and runs ...

Comment: @TibinThomas ... and run that method on that object, with the given args, invoking the implementation of the method that's appropriate to the class of that object. That's what "objc_msgSend" is. There are "class" structs which store meta data about classes. What fields objects of that class have, how big the objects are, how the fields are laid out, what methods the objects support, what protocols the class conforms to, etc.

Comment: Editing the runtime comes down to tinkering with those data structures. You can change what implementations objects invoke fora given method name, you can define new classes entirely, etc.

Comment: For a really cool concrete example of what this can be used for, take a look at [Mike Ash's explanation of how KVO is implemented](https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2009-01-23.html).

Comment: Thanks @Alexander.Is is only possible through message dispatch?. Does java offer the same capabilities?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Predominantly it means two things - the classes and their implementation are defined in the runtime.

## Methods

Objective-C uses dynamic dispatching. When a method is invoked, the runtime actually sends a message (via family of [`objc_msgSend`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/1456712-objc_msgsend) functions) and looks for corresponding method in a class methods table. Even if a method wasn't implemented for a class, dynamic nature of the Objective-C allows to handle or redirect the message by overriding [`resolveInstanceMethod:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/1418500-resolveinstancemethod?language=objc), [`forwardingTargetForSelector:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/1418855-forwardingtargetforselector?language=objc) or [`forwardInvocation:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsproxy/1416417-forwardinvocation?language=objc) methods. You can even add a method in runtime using [`class_addMethod`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/1418901-class_addmethod?language=objc) function or exchange existing implementation of two methods using method-swizzling approach ([`method_exchangeImplementations`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/1418901-class_addmethod?language=objc) function).

## Classes

Thanks to dynamic traits of Objective-C you can change not only methods but also add/set/remove properties and ivars of a class. You can change even a class of an instance in runtime using [`object_setClass`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/1418905-object_setclass?language=objc) function.

There are much more methods that reveal full dynamic power of the Objective-C. You can refer to [Objective-C Runtime page](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/objective-c_runtime?language=objc) for more details about what you can do with them.

Answer (score 0):

Objective-C besides running you code as you expect gives you a lot of possibilities to manipulate it’s behaviour at runtime. 
Basically you can create a class from scratch and add some methods/properties to it when your app is running, or change the implementation of an existing selectors — also known as method swizzling.

By the way, you can find more information here:

https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/AdvancedOperators.html

Comment: This doesn't really answer much, it kind of just repeats snippets of the question.